# What does the script /dev/null do?

Tags: command-line, ssh, screen, su

I was `su`ed into another user to run screen, but I got the error `Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/4' - please check.`

I found a solution: `script /dev/null` and after that I can use screen. Why does this work? It creates a new pseudo terminal?

Comment: Are you sure it is `script /dev/null/`, I believe it is `script /dev/null`. I got an error on my machine with `script /dev/null/`.

Comment: @thefourtheye ????

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On UNIX, this is a virtual-file that can be written to. Data written to this file gets discarded. It is similar to the file call NUL on Windows machines.

Key point; When rooting a machine, intruders will often redirect logging to `/dev/null` For example, the command `ln -s /dev/null` `.bash_history` will cause the system to stop logging bash commands.

In layman's terms, it means much the same thing as black hole. Typical usage: if you don't like what I have to say, please direct your comments to `/dev/null`.

Think of /dev/null as a "black hole." It is the nearest equivalent to a write-only file. Everything written to it disappears forever. Attempts to read or output from it result in nothing. Nevertheless, /dev/null can be quite useful from both the command line and in scripts.

- It discards all data written to it but reports that the write
  operation succeeded.
- It means redirecting both standard output and error to `/dev/null`
- It prevents the script from displaying anything. like windows "echo
  off"

`script /dev/null` prevent any message from appearing on your screen.  It supresses the messages, byt directing them to the "black hole."

Also, have a look at [Why does redirecting 'script' to /dev/null/ allow 'screen' to work while su'ed as another user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/255521/why-does-redirecting-script-to-dev-null-allow-screen-to-work-while-sued-a)

<sup>Source:Linux Dictionary</sup>

Comment: But when I do `script /dev/null` it says `Script started, file is /dev/null`. Why is it so?

Comment: @Mitch I still don't understand how it answers the question. I think the OP wants to know the effect of executing `script /dev/null` and not just about `/dev/null`

Comment: The post what you linked gave me the answer, thanks! :)

Comment: ```script /dev/null prevent any message from appearing on your screen. It supresses the messages, byt directing them to the "black hole."``` - that's bullshit, script makes A COPY OF ALL YOUR MESSAGES in /dev/null, it doesn't hide/supress anything from you

Answer (score 1):

Basically script saves all terminal dialogue into a file, when you specify /dev/null as the file all the stuff script would save into a file would be saved into the black hole.

Answer (score 0):

`script FILE COMMAND...` is used to run `COMMAND` saving a copy of all input and output to `FILE`, while still enabling interactive input/output through your terminal.

`script /dev/null COMMAND...` therefore runs `COMMAND`, and the copy of the output goes to the file `/dev/null`, the bitbucket, in other words it just gets deleted; but the output still goes to your terminal as if you were not using `script`.

What is the purpose of this? It sounds like a pointless step which doesn't achieve anything useful – taking a copy of the output and then sending the copy nowhere. However, it does have one side-effect which is helpful.

Some commands use the `isatty()` function to determine whether stdin/stdout/stderr is a terminal, and they behave differently depending on whether it is or not – for example, they may output ANSI colour codes if stdout is a terminal, but not do so if it is not. That is usually what you want – if you are sending the output to a file or piping it to another program, you usually don't want ANSI escape codes in that output. However, what if you actually do? How can you get the program to send output including ANSI escape codes even when the output isn't a terminal? Some programs have a command line option or environment variable to force colour output even when stdout is not a terminal, but not all do. For programs which lack such a facility to force colour output, `script /dev/null` can be used as a workaround. It will allocate a pseudoterminal, pass that to the command as stdout, and then copy the output sent to that pseudoterminal to its own (non-terminal) stdout. Similarly, some programs (intended for interactive use) refuse to receive input if stdin is not a terminal, so you can't pipe input to them from another program or redirect their input from a file; `script /dev/null` can be used to get around this.